# how to extract the text between two words in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have to extract the text between `</con>` and `<con` in Notepad++ (i.e. delete the text except the one between these 2 words).

My example data is like this:

```
<abstract>
<sentence>The <cons lex="CD4_coreceptor" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD4 coreceptor</cons> interacts with <cons lex="non-polymorphic_region" sem="G#protein_domain_or_region">non-polymorphic regions</cons> of <cons lex="major_histocompatibility_complex_class_II_molecule" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">major histocompatibility complex class II molecules</cons> on <cons lex="antigen-presenting_cell" sem="G#cell_type">antigen-presenting cells</cons> and contributes to <cons lex="T_cell_activation" sem="G#other_name">T cell activation</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>We have investigated the effect of <cons lex="CD4_triggering" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="CD4" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD4</cons> triggering</cons> on <cons lex="T_cell_activating_signal" sem="G#other_name">T cell activating signals</cons> in a <cons lex="lymphoma_model" sem="G#other_name">lymphoma model</cons> using <cons lex="monoclonal_antibody" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">monoclonal antibodies</cons> (<cons lex="mAb" sem="G#protein_domain_or_region">mAb</cons>) which recognize different <cons lex="CD4_epitope" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">CD4 epitopes</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>We demonstrate that <cons lex="CD4_triggering" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="CD4" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD4</cons> triggering</cons> delivers signals capable of activating the <cons lex="NF-AT_transcription_factor" sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-AT transcription factor</cons> which is required for <cons lex="interleukin-2_gene_expression" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="interleukin-2" sem="G#protein_molecule">interleukin-2</cons> gene expression</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>Whereas different <cons lex="anti-CD4_mAb" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">anti-CD4 mAb</cons> or <cons lex="HIV-1_gp120" sem="G#protein_molecule"><cons lex="HIV-1" sem="G#virus">HIV-1</cons> gp120</cons> could all trigger activation of the <cons lex="protein_tyrosine_kinase" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">protein tyrosine kinases</cons> <cons lex="p56lck" sem="G#protein_molecule">p56lck</cons> and <cons lex="p59fyn" sem="G#protein_molecule">p59fyn</cons> and phosphorylation of the <cons lex="Shc_adaptor_protein" sem="G#protein_molecule">Shc adaptor protein</cons>, which mediates signals to <cons lex="Ras" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">Ras</cons>, they differed significantly in their ability to activate <cons lex="NF-AT" sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-AT</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>Lack of full activation of <cons lex="NF-AT" sem="G#protein_molecule">NF-AT</cons> could be correlated to a dramatically reduced capacity to induce <cons lex="calcium_flux" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="calcium" sem="G#atom">calcium</cons> flux</cons> and could be complemented with a <cons lex="calcium_ionophore" sem="G#other_organic_compound">calcium ionophore</cons>.</sentence>
<sentence>The results identify functionally distinct <cons lex="epitope" sem="G#protein_family_or_group">epitopes</cons> on the <cons lex="CD4_coreceptor" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD4 coreceptor</cons> involved in activation of the <cons lex="Ras/protein_kinase_C_and_calcium_pathway" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="Ras/protein_kinase_C" sem="G#protein_molecule"><cons lex="Ras/protein_kinase_C_pathway" sem="G#other_name"><cons lex="Ras" sem="G#protein_molecule">Ras</cons><cons lex="protein_kinase_C" sem="G#protein_molecule">/protein kinase C</cons></cons></cons> and <cons lex="calcium_pathway" sem="G#other_name">calcium pathways</cons></cons>.</sentence>
 </abstract>
```

My desired out put is:

```
interacts with 
of 
on 
and contributes to
on 
in 
using 
which recognize different 
triggering
delivers signals capable of activating the
which is required for 
or 
could all trigger activation of the 
and
```

I tried the regex `.*<\/cons>(.*?)<cons.*` and replace with `$1` but that only gives me the data in the last occurrence of the `</con>` and `<con` of each `<sentence>` while my sentences contains more than one occurrence of these tags.

Anyone who can help me??

Comment: Note that example has nested `<cons>` tags (e.g. `<cons lex="CD4_triggering" sem="G#other_name">
   <cons lex="CD4" sem="G#protein_molecule">CD4</cons> triggering</cons>`). Regular expression might not be the best way to extract data. I would rather suggest a XML parser in a **Python** or **Perl** script.

Answer (score 6):

Use this `.*Word1(.*?)Word2.*` expression also don't forget to add escape character `/` if you are dealing with any symbols.

Comment: `/` doesn't need to be escaped in Npp regex.

Comment: I was searching for `Failed for [] = [ABC]` when I used `.*Failed for \[(.*?)\] = \[ABC\].*` then it worked but was failing when I used `.*Failed for [(.*?)] = [ABC].*` So I had to escape `[` and `]` in order to work

Answer (score 2):

Make a search and replace using regular expressions.

<s>Change search mode to "Regular expression" and replace `<[^>]*>` with nothing.</s>

*EDIT*

Change search mode to "Regular expression" and replace `.*<\/cons>(.*?)<cons.*` with `$1`.

Comment: I write <[^>]> in find what text box and keep the replace text box empty by keeping regular expression but it did not worked

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a `*`

Comment: where to place this??

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Comment: It jst only removed the tags while i want something else dear

Comment: I tried once again the regx of the Jimmy T , It worked well on the whole data but the problem is that this only gave me the the last occurance of the data between </con> and <con of a sentence while a sentence may contain more than one occurences of the words </con> and <con

Comment: @ Jimmy  T , i need ur help

Comment: I think there is a need of more than one occurencess, nayone who can help me?????????????????? and how will i use this??????